# OpenCV Watershed : 4 point connectivity

Tags: c++, image-processing, computer-vision, morphological-analysis, watershed

I am writing a code for watershed in OpenCV.

But i want the watershed boundaries to be 4 point connected and not 8 point.

Currently this is the interface:

```
void watershed(InputArray image, InputOutputArray markers)
```

Does anybody have any solution for this?

Also, is there any simple way to perform morphological watershed in opencv for automatic over-segmentation, the current one takes user input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV help for [watershed](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=watershed#watershed) does not explicitly explain the connectivity used in the function. It just refers to the paper MEYER, Fernand. Color image segmentation. In: *Image Processing and its Applications, 1992., International Conference on*. IET, 1992. p. 303-306.

Maybe you have to implement your own watershed algorithm, starting from the one available in OpenCV (OpenCV 2.4 implementation is [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/imgproc/src/segmentation.cpp#L80)), or creating a new one; for example the following paper describes an algorithm where the connectivity is properly highlighted:

[VINCENT, Luc; SOILLE, Pierre. Watersheds in digital spaces: an efficient algorithm based on immersion simulations. *IEEE transactions on pattern analysis and machine intelligence*, 1991, 13.6: 583-598.](http://csce.uark.edu/~jgauch/library/Segmentation/Vincent.1991.pdf)