# How to get all the local "peaks" from a picture?

Tags: opencv, watershed

I would like to get all the small peaks from the picture below. I would also like to avoid getting the big peak (on the right), but I can exclude that based on the area. The image is a result of Sobel operator but this is not important. It will be used as markers for watershed algorithm. This is not the only picture I have to process and I can't relay on the values of the peaks only on the fact that they are "local maximums". Notice that contour detection won't work as some small bumps are connected. The picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may find Chapter 4 "Peaks and Ridges" of my [thesis 1999](https://research-repository.uwa.edu.au/en/publications/local-energy-feature-tracing-in-digital-images-and-volumes) useful. It uses the concept of the watershed algorithm, implemented using Vincent's ordered pixel implementation. Algorithm details are in the thesis. I have not been working in the area for many years so have not done an opencv implementation.

@[Alessandro Jacopson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15485/alessandro-jacopson) provides the following link in another SO watershed [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219670/opencv-watershed-4-point-connectivity) :

[VINCENT, Luc; SOILLE, Pierre. Watersheds in digital spaces: an efficient algorithm based on immersion simulations. IEEE transactions on pattern analysis and machine intelligence, 1991, 13.6: 583-598.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a381/9dda9a5f00dbb8cd3413ca7422e37a0d5794.pdf)